# Two personalized functions in the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I have this:

```
import time 
import sys

# Função Linha:

def lin():
   lin = "=" * 30
   for char in lin:
      print(char, end='')
      time.sleep(0.1)

# Função "Acertou!"

def acertou():
    acerto = "Right!"
    for char in acerto:
       print(char, end='')
       time.sleep(0.2)

# Função "Errou!"

  def errou():
     erro = "Wrong!"
     for char in erro:
         print(char, end='')
         time.sleep(0.15)

# Programa Principal

primeira_resposta = "Nitrogen"
primeira_questão = input("What gas makes the sky blue?")

if primeira_questão == primeira_resposta:
    lin()
    acertou()
    lin()
```

and so on, i removed somethings like more questions, and something here are in portuguese, ( i´m portuguese ), and i noticed an error: the lin() function print something like this:

```
===============================Right!==============================(next question)
```

all in the same line, how i can make this print the lin(), the "Right" and the Next Question in different lines?

Comment: It would be nicer if your functions returned *what* to print (string) and then you would just call them with the `print` function. Like this: `print(lin()); print(acertou()); print(lin())`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to print a new line after the `lin()` loop

```
def lin():
   lin = "=" * 30
   for char in lin:
      print(char, end='')
      time.sleep(0.1)
   print()
```

Or

```
lin()
print()
acertou()  # Next question
```